# Cannot properly access url variable with isset get from another page

Tags: php, jquery, session, url, isset

I cannot access url php variable on page2.php
Im trying to display a list of reviews on another page for each product user click on.

When I used `if(isset($_GET['product_name']))` in my `product_details.php` page, it works fine but not in 'page2.php'

I also tried using SESSION to get the product_name on page2.php but since im using a while-loop to display all the product-items on product_details.php page, when I used

`if(isset($_SESSION['product_name'])) {
$prod_title = "$_SESSION['product_name']"; ...`

Im only getting the last item on the product_list.

URL: `http://localhost/Test_run/product_details.php?product_name=Hair comb set`

product_details.php - contain mostly html form and jquery

```
  $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  $prod_title = $row['product_name'];

  <script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    fetch_data();

    function fetch_data() {

        var review_operation = "fetch";
        $.ajax({
            url: "page2.php?product_name=", <- //what should i put here?
            method: "POST",
            data: {review_operation: review_operation},
            success: function (data) {
                $('#reviews_data').html(data);

            }
        });

    }
 </script>
```

page2.php - contain the php code to fetch the result

```
if(isset($_POST["review_operation"])) {

session_start();
require_once('database_text.php');
$heidisql = pdo_con();

 if(isset($_GET['product_name'])) {

    $prod_title = $_GET['product_name']; 

    if ($_POST["review_operation"] == "fetch") {

 Extected result: $prod_title = url_variable(in this case - Hair comb set)
 Actual result: blank, no data is being fetched...i think
```

Comment: You pass no GET parameters in your AJAX call.

Comment: does not work even if i used `method: "GET"`

Comment: Even if you change it to GET, you'd be sending `review_operation`, not `product_name`. Keep POST, but your `url` line should include the `?product_name=fadfalkdj` bit.

Comment: Im not sure Im properly understand what you are saying, cause in my url `?product_name=variable` does appear in the product details page!

Comment: It's not the product_details page that's using it though is it. It's `page2.php`, the one you're not sending it to. You seem to think that because you've passed it into the page that has an AJAX request, that the AJAX request will magically send the data on, but that's not what it does.

Comment: Im displaying data from page2 to the product_details page, page2 only contain codes to fetch the different data related to that specific product.

Comment: I'll try again. `page2.php` expects there to be a `GET` parameter set called `product_name` (`if(isset($_GET['product_name']))`). You make a request via AJAX. You are not sending `product_name` to `page2.php` (see `url: "page2.php",`). `page2.php` and `product_details.php` are called in different requests.

Comment: Then what should I do to get access of product_name in product_details, anything more specific?

Comment: I've already said exactly what you need to do. Add `?product_name=adfasdf` to the end of the `url` parameter in your AJAX call.